# Unmet broken dependencies debian

Tags: debian, package-management

I know there a lot of such question were asked, but no one answer helped me.

Here is an error I beat with for few hours already.

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
 imagemagick-6.q16 : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
                     recommends: libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
prince : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
vlc : Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-plugin-vedio-output (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-l10n (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.7-1)  but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 3.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
xserver-xorg: Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all but it is not going to be installed or
                       xorg-driver-video
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Here is my `source.list`:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS                    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Security updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

## Debian mirror

# Base repository
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

# Stable updates
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free

# Stable backports
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

I tried `apt-get clean` and `sudo apt --fix-broken install` - nothing helped me. I tried comment out repositories in source.list one by one and run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but get the same error.

If I'll run `sudo apt-get install -f` or `sudo apt --fix-broken install` one more error messeage starts appear in console

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be cause by help packages
```

Running `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` shows nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably it will help somebody. I resolved an issue by removing all problem dependencies using `dpkg --remove --purge <name>`. After that I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` again.

Comment: `aptitude` is my go-to tool to fix broken dependencies. Though the UI takes a bit to get used to. You added it as tag, but didn't mention it in the question. And yes, you'll need to manually work through it, upgrading packages or uninstalling them as necessary.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question. Comments are not meant for answers. You indicated that it will probably help someone. They will have easier time finding it if it is posted as an answer. Comments are too easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution in the comments.

> Probably it will help somebody. I resolved an issue by removing all problem dependencies using `dpkg --remove --purge <name>`. After that I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` again.